# CakePHP 3 - Como fazer rollback

Tags: cakephp-3, transações, model

No cakephp 2 nos os saves de forma transacional com `$data_source->begin();` ,`$data_source->commit();`, ou `$data_source->rollback();`.
Então quando eu precisava inserir em mais de uma tabela, e os dados fosse dependentes caso ocorresse qualquer erro eu fazia o *rollback*
lendo a documentação do cakephp 3, vi mudou o processo, mas eu não consegui reproduzir.

No trecho de código abaixo depois de salvar no model *Users*, eu quero salvar o *Tokens*, mas caso ocorra um erro no *Tokens* quero fazer rollback no *Users*.

por exemplo, a entidade Tokens é obrigatório ter o campo "token", quando entrar na exception quer fazer rollback e não registrar no banco o User.
Mas quando faço o Users sempre é salvo no banco.

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $return = $connection->transactional(function ($connection) use($json) {
        try {
            $obj = $this->Users->newEntity();
            $obj = $this->Users->patchEntity($obj, $json);

            $User = $this->Users->save($obj);

            //$token["token"] = $json["google_token"];//forçando erro
            $token["user_id"] = $User->id; 

            $obj = $this->Tokens->newEntity();
            $obj = $this->Tokens->patchEntity($obj, $token);
            $Token = $this->Tokens->save($obj);

            $return["success"] = true;
            $return["message"] = "Cadastrado com sucesso";
            $return["data"] = $User; 

            //fazer o commit
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $return["success"] = false;
            $return["data"] = $e->getMessage();
            $return["message"] = "Falha ao cadastrar ";

            //fazer o rollback
        }
        return $return;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fui sabotado pelo MySql Workbench.

Ele gerava as tabelas com a engine MyISAM que não possui suporte ao rollback, mesmo estando marcado como InnoDB.

Resolvendo isso funcionou.